# How to initiate request from java web application to android client

Tags: java, android

I need help in this task plz: i need to implement the request from a server as java web application, to android clients, that means first of all, android client login from his application, after that i need that the server initiate a request anytime and send it to clients, for example ask him for a help, and waiting their replies.

Comment: For the "service initiate a request anytime and send it to clients", use [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

Comment: It may be easier to get help if you try to write some code first and then ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) service.